# Remove a function without breaking my code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a site search feature on my web app, but I want to remove a redundant radio button input.

The original code allowed you to choose a search engine, using three radio buttons. I've removed three of the buttons, but I can't figure out how to remove the last one. I just want to use google by default.

```js
// All-in-one Internal Site Search script- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
// For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/
// This notice must stay intact for use

//Enter domain of site to search.
var domainroot = "ts.xxxxxxx.net"

var searchaction = [ //form action for the 3 search engines
  "http://www.google.com/search"

]

var queryfieldname = ["q", "p", "q"] //name of hidden query form for the 3 search engines

function switchaction(cur, index) {
  cur.form.action = searchaction[index]
  document.getElementById("hiddenquery").name = queryfieldname[index]
}

function jksitesearch(curobj) {
  for (i = 0; i < document.jksearch.se.length; i++) { //loop through radio to see which is checked
    if (document.jksearch.se[i].checked == true)
      switchaction(document.jksearch.se[i], i)
  }
  document.getElementById("hiddenquery").value = "site:" + domainroot + " " + curobj.qfront.value
}
```

```html
<form name="jksearch" action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="jksitesearch(this)">


  <input id="hiddenquery" type="hidden" name="q" />
  <input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 200px" value="" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /><br />
  <div style="font: bold 11px Verdana;"><input name="se" type="radio" checked>
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Make it `<input type=hidden ...` with the value set to the Google choice.

Comment: Delete the `input` from the page, and the code that references it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input `type='hidden'` and set `value='1'` to achieve the same result.

If you must keep the radio button in the form for some reason, set `display:none;` on the parent node for the input.

```js
// All-in-one Internal Site Search script- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
// For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/
// This notice must stay intact for use

//Enter domain of site to search.
var domainroot = "ts.kiwiroad.net"

var searchaction = [ //form action for the 3 search engines
  "http://www.google.com/search"

]

var queryfieldname = ["q", "p", "q"] //name of hidden query form for the 3 search engines

function switchaction(cur, index) {
  cur.form.action = searchaction[index]
  document.getElementById("hiddenquery").name = queryfieldname[index]
}

function jksitesearch(curobj) {
  for (i = 0; i < document.jksearch.se.length; i++) { //loop through radio to see which is checked
    if (document.jksearch.se[i].checked == true)
      switchaction(document.jksearch.se[i], i)
  }
  document.getElementById("hiddenquery").value = "site:" + domainroot + " " + curobj.qfront.value
}

// console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="se"]').value);
```

```html
<form name="jksearch" action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="jksitesearch(this)">
  <input id="hiddenquery" type="hidden" name="q" />
  <input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 200px" value="" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /><br />
  <div style="font: bold 11px Verdana;">
    <input name="se" type="hidden" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It has the same behavior as your original code except there are no more radio buttons and no more functions relating to them.

```js
// All-in-one Internal Site Search script- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
// For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/
// This notice must stay intact for use

//Enter domain of site to search.
var domainroot = "ts.xxxxxxx.net"

var searchaction = [ //form action for the 3 search engines
  "http://www.google.com/search"

]

function jksitesearch(curobj) {
  document.getElementById("hiddenquery").value = "site:" + domainroot + " " + curobj.qfront.value
}
```

```html
<form name="jksearch" action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="jksitesearch(this)">


  <input id="hiddenquery" type="hidden" name="q" />
  <input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 200px" value="" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /><br />

</form>
```